# Screen appearing differently on different devices even with dip and same resolution

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-relativelayout, android-resolution

Okay guys. Problem: I have a layout that needs views to appear inside of the "boxes" that are built into the background image. So..precise layout is a must. I got the layout up and it looked great on the emulator and the Samsung Galaxy S, but when I throw it on the Droid X the views are shifted up. The problem is that both phones are considered Medium Screens with HDPI. I obviously can't use different layout folders to fix it. I have "anyDensity" set to false in the manifest. Tried the minSDK  3 trick. My resources are pulling from the drawable-hdpi folder, but shouldn't make a difference. The only thing I can imagine would be causing this is the specific margin values I'm giving (even in DIP). But I have no idea how to achieve a layout with views in specific locations without this. Any help please?? Commonsware where are you on this one. Thanks guys.

**Edit:**
    The more I think about it, the more I realize I was wrong in my thinking. (it has been a while since I coded Android layout) DIP is doing exactly what it should be. The sizes are exactly the same on every screen I put them on, but what I'm wanting to accomplish is to have the view expand with the screen size. So if the screen is larger the margins and spacing grow with the screen. Essentially I need a fill_parent for my entire layout, but I can't use that with precise layout. Any ideas?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Text Here"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textColor="#253B85" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="5D6"
        android:textSize="9dip"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="90dip"
            android:layout_height="90dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Really Long Name"
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:textColor="#253B85" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/importantInfo"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="50% off"
            android:textSize="30dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#253B85" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/icon"
            android:text="date: "
            android:textColor="#253B85" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/icon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dateLabel"
            android:text=" "
            android:textColor="#253B85" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/moreInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="33dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/dateLabel"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:text=" "
            android:textColor="#253B85" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/qrIcon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="106dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/moreInfo" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="160dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="buttonRedeemOnClickListener"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:text="Redeemed Coupon"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: :) It's because of the size: Motorola is 480 x 854 pixels, while Galaxy S is 480 x 800 pixels, but for Android, both are considered large, as they have at least 640dp x 480dp. See also this [table](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing).

Comment: I completely understand that the phone screens are not the same. My issue is that the layouts are not expanding to match. That is what I need help with.

Comment: Maybe it is happening because the way your background drawable is being scaled.

Comment: Well. I considered that, but that shouldn't be the case. The views are laid out with the exact same margins and same location on both phones. If you hold the phones next to each other the views with their spacing is identical. However, the Droid X is a larger phone so the the views need to expand down to fill the phone. If the image didn't scale there would be a black bar across the bottom so I'm doubting that's the issue. The image is accounting for the new amount of real estate, but the views are not. Almost like an absolute layout thing. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Add in manifest file:::

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens>
```

Comment: Still shifting. I might note that I've noticed the margins are the same, but the background is expanding with the Droid X but the margins aren't expanding. How would I achieve the same expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code currently, I don't think you have tried coding different layouts for different sizes. It's time consuming depending on how many sizes you are going to code for, but well worth the trouble of doing so. The only issue I can see is if you are going to make a layout for every screen resolution, which is not worth the trouble.